# How to configure a standalone performance test for HBA/CNA interface cards using iperf

Tags: linux, centos-7, pci-express, iperf

I’m looking for a solution to run a performance test to an HBA and CNA interface cards on a stand-alone server running Linux OS (e.g Centos7), without having to connect it to another server/switch.

I have 3 types of cards - IB, ISCSI, FC:

```
Mellanox Technologies MT27600 [Connect-IB]
Mellanox Technologies MT27520 Family [ConnectX-3 Pro]
QLogic Corp. ISP8324-based 16Gb Fiber Channel
```

The goal is to ensure that the card's performance is according to the spec.

Server configuration: Each card has two ports connected via a loopback cable between the ports.

My question is how to configure these cards to allows me to perform a performance test between 2 ports of the same card using a utility like iperf.

Thanks,

Comment: I'd try to put the network interface for one port of each card into a network namespace, assign IP addresses, then use iperf as usual (one instance on the port in the main network namespace, one instance in the loopbacked port in the new network namespace).

Comment: Can you elaborate or give some examples?
For instance, one of my cards has 2 ports which represented as 2 interfaces in ifconfig, e.g  eth3 and eth4.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to put the network interface for one port of each card into a network namespace, assign IP addresses, then use iperf as usual (one instance on the port in the main network namespace, one instance in the loopbacked port in the new network namespace).

Details (untested): Something along the lines of

```
NS=ns1
IF1=eth3
IF2=eth4
ADDR1=10.0.0.1
ADDR2=10.0.0.2
ip netns add $NS
ip set $IF1 nets $NS
ip -n $NS addr add $ADDR1/24 dev $IF1
ip -n $NS link set $IF1 up
ip addr add $ADDR2/24 dev $IF2
ip link set $IF2 up
```

as root (sudo) should move one interface into a newly created network namespace, assign IP addresses, and activate the links. Now start an xterm (I prefer colored ones so I don't confuse them) in the new network namespace as the normal user `your_user`,

```
ip netns exec $NS su -c "xterm -bg $COL &" your_user
```

and run `iperf -s` in that window and `iperf -c $ADDR1` in the main namespace (or vice versa, it shouldn't matter).

If something doesn't work, debug with `ping`, `tcpdump` etc. Having windows for both network namespaces makes debugging easy.